# Rewrite all url index to subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website with many subfolders and problem with duplicate content example: https://example.com/sub1/ and https://example.com/sub1/index.html. How to rewrite all to only subfolder see without index.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)index\.html /$1 [END]
```

That rule will work likewise in the http server's host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") inside the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. You should always prefer the first variant if possible for various reasons.

In case you receive back a server internal error (http status 500) using above rule changes are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite references to an unsupported `END` flag in that case in your server's error log file. Try using the `L` flag instead. It might work the same, though that depends a bit on your actual setup.

Comment: L and END flag is 500 internal. I upload my htaccess maybe you look :) https://pastebin.com/pi7J561b

Comment: With a http status 500 you need to take a look into your http server's error log file, that is where you can read what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/index\.(html|htm)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```